# Load more when scroll to bottom from database using GET variables- PHP/ Mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to load first 10 results on my webpage then a load more button to load next 10 result using AJAX on the same page. There can be two types of URLs of my web pages.

```
1.  www.example.com/list.php?name=ABC&area=All
2.  www.example.com/list.php?name=ABC&area=BCD
```

If someone types URL manually and there is a mismatch in name and area means name or area doesn’t match to the database results than he/she will be redirected to error404.php.

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var track_page = 1;
    load_contents(track_page);

    $("#load_more_button").click(function (e) { 
        track_page++; 
        load_contents(track_page);
    });

    function load_contents(track_page){
        $('.animation_image').show();

        $.post( 'fetch_pages.php', {'page': track_page}, function(data){

            if(data.trim().length == 0){
                $("#load_more_button").text("You have reached end of the record!").prop("disabled", true);
            }

            $("#results").append(data);

            $('.animation_image').hide();
        });
    }
</script>
```

**list.php**

```
$_SESSION['name']=$_GET['name'];
$_SESSION['area']=$_GET['area'];

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="results"></div>

    <button id="load_more_button"><img src="ajax-loader.gif"  class="animation_image" style="float:left;"> Load More</button>
</div>
```

**Fetch_pages.php**

```
include("db.php");
$item_per_page = 10;
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
$sort="id";
if(isset($_GET['sort'])&&($_GET['sort'])=='ASC'){
    $sort="price ASC";
}
elseif(isset($_GET['sort'])&&($_GET['sort'])=='DESC'){
    $sort="price DESC";
}
if($_SESSION['area']=='All'){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from table where name= ? ORDER BY $sort LIMIT ?,?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sdd", $_SESSION['name'], $position, $item_per_page);
}
else{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from table where name= ? AND area= ? ORDER BY $sort LIMIT ?,?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssdd", $_SESSION['name'], $_SESSION['area'], $position, $item_per_page);
}
    $stmt->execute();
    $i=1;
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row4=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
       ---------------
       ---------------
}
```

The above script works fine if no GET variable is available in URL. But If i want to load page content on basis of $_GET variable it gives an error that $_GET variable not defined. Where i need to define these variables.. I also have tried defining S_SESSION variables on fetch_pages.php along with list.php but it still gives an error.

What is the best way to do this ? Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your *list.php* like this to access data using both `post` and `get`

```
<?php
$_SESSION['name']=$_REQUEST['name'];
$_SESSION['area']=$_REQUEST['area'];
?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="results"></div>

    <button id="load_more_button"><img src="ajax-loader.gif"  class="animation_image" style="float:left;"> Load More</button>
```

**EDIT**

If you don't have to use session try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var track_page = 1;
    load_contents(track_page);

    $("#load_more_button").click(function (e) { 
        track_page++; 
        load_contents(track_page);
    });

    function load_contents(track_page){
        $('.animation_image').show();

        $.post( 'fetch_pages.php', {'page': track_page,'name' : '<?=$_GET['name']?>',area:'<?=$_GET['area']?>'}, function(data){

            if(data.trim().length == 0){
                $("#load_more_button").text("You have reached end of the record!").prop("disabled", true);
            }

            $("#results").append(data);

            $('.animation_image').hide();
        });
    }
</script>
```

And in **Fetch_pages.php** change `$_SESSION` to `$_POST`

Comment: I have also checked assigning a direct value to $_SESSION instead GET, POST and REQUEST....It doesn't work in that case also...

Comment: Have you started session? `session_start()` in your file

Comment: I haven't started it before...but it is not making any effect even after starting session...

Comment: I have also tried changing $_SESSION into $_REQUEST in fetch_pages.php.....It doesn't make any effect...

Comment: Is there any way that i could pass my get variables into script so that it could be use as post variables in fetch_pages.php.... ??

Comment: Hi I have made changes according to you...changed script portion like this "$.post( 'fetch_pages.php', {'page': track_page, 'name' : '<?php $_GET['name']?>', 'area' : '<?php $_GET['area']?>'}, function(data){" and changed $_SESSION to $_POST in fetch_pages.php.....Still Its not loading content...Output is "You have reached end of record".

Answer (score 0):

Use $_POST instead of $_GET in php or send via $.get() in javascript. Currently your javascript is sending the data as post variables as the method $.post() is called to send the data back to the server.

Comment: Change $.post() to $.get() in javascript.

Comment: OK. Change that back. Then in your php, on the line that errors, use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET. This will work in both scenarios.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: area in C:\wamp\www\mysites\fetch_pages.php on line 18

Comment: This is because $_SESSION['area'] hasn't been set yet in fetch_pages.php. You can either set it, or you can check it exists with isset() before you read it.

Comment: This error occurs when i change $_SESSION to $_REQUEST in my fetch_pages.php and in bind_param i change accordingly....

Comment: ANd if i change $_GET to $_REQUEST in list.php...Then i get error "Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\mysites\fetch_pages.php on line 18"...

Comment: AND if i use isset for SESSION variable, It shows that your have been reached at end of results...

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing in the GET variables in your javascript, you have to supply `name` and `area` variables in your `$.post` call.

Also you are using `$.post` which makes the variables available via `$_POST` in PHP.

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge of jquery...Can you please type the right code here ??